# Android Studio not recognising raw file on windows 10

Tags: android, android-videoview

I have added a raw file to my Res file but in java its not recognising the raw file or the mp4 file. Please see screen shot with highlights below

[image]

Comment: What guide/documentation are you reading on VideoView? Please link me to the page

Comment: I am not using any guide I undertook a course on Udemy, was a Macuser never had this problem this is what the screen shot actually looks like.

Comment: Start looking at guides. Right now you're just guessing code. This shouldn't work on your mac, that's just an excuse.

Comment: Maybe you should speak to Rob Percival on this, plus the app i built last year using this code worked a treat

Comment: No, I'm not gonna talk with him about this. The code doesn't work. Period. Also, it's your error, not mine.

Comment: You're the one who should speak to him.

Comment: For all we know it's a stupid problem because you included the .mp4 part in your R.raw variable :)))

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reproduce the video, see the code below.

```
VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView_video);

Uri path = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/"+ R.raw.starwars);

videoView.setVideoURI(path);
videoView.start();
```

Remove the extension (.mp4)